# Estimating road network distances when database queries are expensive

Tags: network, road, distance-matrix

I have a large number `N` of points and I'd like to build their distance matrix with respect to a road network.

Unfortunately, I am not able to perform all `N^2` queries to build this matrix, so some of these distances have to be approximated, using a limited number of queries together with other information (e.g. crow-flies distances between points).  Are there any well-known methods for doing this?

For example, I could take each point and only look at the distances to some of its nearest neighbors, as well as a few randomly selected points, and then solve some sort of regression model on this, but I would imagine that someone thought of a much more clever scheme at some point.